# Why the badPwdCount, Last-Logon Last-Logoff are non replicated?

Tags: active-directory

Just wondering why the following attributes are non replicated?  badPwdCount, Last-Logon,Last-Logoff . As far as i know these attributes are pertaining to one domain controller but why it will not be replicated to another domain controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lastlogon attribute is not replicated, but the lastlogontimestamp attribute is. The latter is replicated every 14 days. MS uses such a large interval in order to save bandwidth. If MS saw a reason to replicate that more often, they would do it more often.

badpwcount - possibly the same reason
last-logoff: not in use! Should be empty on all DCs.